# Chrome Extension to get URL and append ending

Tags: url, google-chrome

I am very new to js and chrome extentions and am trying to make a chrome extension that gets the current tabs url and adds a '&flash=on' at the end. my code doesn't seem to want to work right

```
manifest.json

    {
  "name": "FlashOn Chrome",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Changes default to flash player",
"permissions": [
    "tabs"],
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.stream.com/*"],

      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ]
}


script.js

    function updateUrl(tab){

       var currentURL = tab.url

       var newurl = currentURL.replace(currentUrl + "&flash=on");
       chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: newurl});}   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {updateUrl(tab);});
```

its for a streaming site that has html5 video and flash video but the flash is only accessible by adding the &flash=on to the end of the url

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here: are you trying to change the location of the page, from the current URL to the URL with &flash=on` added on to it?

Also -- the script here seems to be incomplete: could you provide a complete script?

One obvious problem: you've got currentURL and currentUrl:

```
var newurl = currentURL.replace(currentUrl + "&flash=on");
```

Note that in a content script you can get and set the URL of the page with location.href.